# How do I read a char from a user in the command line

Tags: java, char

How do I read a char from a user in the command line. I am familiar with readInt(). Is there something like this for chars.

This is for the stanford course I am taking online as part of stanford engineering everywhere over the summer and I need to finish soon before my high school term starts.

---

Is there any way I can do this using the acm.util, acm.program acm.util, or java.awt class because that's all I'm allowed for the assignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
final char c = dis.readChar();
```

Answer (score 6):

The java.util.Scanner class was pretty much built for this :), but oddly remains something of a hidden secret as not many people know about it.

Comment: I remember when I was teaching Java during Grad School, the text book mentioned the scanner class and I had to quickly go look it up before class to make sure I knew it - I had never heard of it before then.  +1 for obscure knowledge :)

Comment: @aperkins: The Scanner class didn't come around until Java 5 and didn't seem as heavily advertised as some of its other features.

Comment: JDK 1.5 has only been out for, what, 4 years? :)

Comment: Yeah, but "read from the command line" is something you usually don't return to after learning it in Java 101.  :-)  +2 for this answer if I could give it.